# Cannot open embedded hyperlink in PDF generated using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox, acrobat

I have used PDFBox version 2.0 to generated a PDF containing a clickable URL.

```
// Create a new annotation and make it invisible
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
txtLink.setInvisible(true);

// Add an action
PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
action.setURI(url);
txtLink.setAction(action);

// Create a new rectangle that will be the clickable area
PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
position.setLowerLeftX(currentXpos);
position.setLowerLeftY(currentYpos - rectangleHeight);
position.setUpperRightX(currentXpos + rectangleWidth);
position.setUpperRightY(currentYpos);

 // Write the "Link" string in blue 
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.blue);
contentStream.showText(elm.text());
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.black);

// Make the rectangle a clickable link and add it to the page
txtLink.setRectangle(position);
page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```

When I click on the generated PDF in Chrome 45, the document is opened in the Chrome's PDF viewer. The link is clickable, no problem.

If I click on the generated PDF in Firefox (41.0.1) or IE 11, the document is loaded in the Adobe PDF viewer plugin and the link is not clickable. The mouse-over displays the correct URL, but nothing happens when I click the link.

Is this a security issue? Is there anything I can do in the PDFBox code to make the link clickable always?

Comment: What results do you get when opening the file in Acrobat/Reader? How does the link look in the Link tool in Acrobat?

Comment: If I download the PDF file and open it in Acrobat Reader, the mouse-over shows the correct URL, but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: Correction, Adobe Reader. I do not have access to Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: After having played around a bit with the code, i discovered that if the clickable area rectangle is set to invisible, then it is not clickable in some cases.

    `txtLink.setInvisible(false);`

After setting it to false, the link is clickable in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Great, that you got the issue solved. And it looks to me that you discovered a (IMHO) nasty bug in PDFBox, because the active area and its bounding rectangle are independent when it comes to the visibility property. In other words, hiding the border must not hide the active area. A workaround would be, if you can access it, to set the width of the border to 0, if you don't want to display a border around the active area.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to hide the border by setting the width to 0.

    `// Create a new annotation and make it visible`
    `PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();`
    `txtLink.setInvisible(false);`

    `// Set the border to zero to hide it`
    `PDBorderStyleDictionary border =  new PDBorderStyleDictionary();`
    `border.setWidth(0);`
    `txtLink.setBorderStyle(border);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to hide the border by setting the width to 0:

```
// Create a new annotation and make it visible
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
txtLink.setInvisible(false);

// Set the border to zero to hide it
PDBorderStyleDictionary border = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
border.setWidth(0);

txtLink.setBorderStyle(border);
```

Comment: Is that in any way an answer to the question?